# Get the output of a pipe cmd

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to make a script that filters every country in an csv file.

What do I need to make ?

If I do this:
`cat students.csv | ./mycommand.sh`

The echo don't display anything from the pipe.

The content of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

output=$(2>&1)

# I have tried this too

output=$($?)
```

My csv file:

```
lecler_o;tek2;TLS
le-coa_m;tek2;REN
lecomt_d;tek1;PAR
...
```

This doesn't display anything.

Comment: Provide an example of CSV file that you are using...

Comment: okay I ill upload it

Comment: Anyway, if the file is a CSV, the fields are separated by commas (","). You may just need to use the cut command : cat file.csv | cut -d, -f"field_number"

Comment: Yeah but I'm a noob at English so I will translate that I need to do

Comment: You want to extract the country or the town ? Because TLS is Toulouse, REN is Rennes and PAR is Paris ? For the town : cat file.csv | cut -d\; -f3  (don't forget to escape ";" with "\" otherwise it will be interpreted as a end of command line).

Comment: Yeah this is that I need to do, I need to have one argument that take the Country that I want to display, if the country does not exist I just cat the file

Comment: But I need to extract every line who them have the country

Comment: I have find with the grep command that work well thank you you really help me to be at the good rails :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write a script, using the location as an input parameter, something as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep $1 students.csv
```

Imagine you call this `mycommand.sh`, then launching the following:

```
mycommand.sh "PAR"
```

Should give you following result:

```
lecomt_d;tek1;PAR
```

Is it something like this you're looking for?